# QSpinbox with binary numbers

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qspinbox

Is it possible to have spinbox with binary inputs. Lets say "10010". and scroll up and down does binary increment/decrement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the [`displayIntegerBase`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qspinbox.html#displayIntegerBase-prop) property to 2 to use the binary system:

```py
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtWidgets


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = QtWidgets.QSpinBox()
    w.setValue(0b10010)
    w.setDisplayIntegerBase(2)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**Update:**

If you want to set a minimum width (in this case 5) then the [`textFromValue()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qspinbox.html#textFromValue) method must be overridden:

```py
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtWidgets


class SpinBox(QtWidgets.QSpinBox):
    def textFromValue(self, value):
        return "{:05b}".format(value)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = SpinBox()
    w.setMaximum(0b11111)
    w.setValue(0b00000)
    w.setDisplayIntegerBase(2)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. exactly what I was looking for

Comment: I want to show "00000" for w.setValue(0b00000). I am able to get only 0. is there a way to modify.thanks.